# Merge files with different columns and rows linux

Tags: awk

I have some files that I need join, I have looked for some solutions but they do not fit what I need, I have the following files

a.csv

> date      |A|B|C|D
>   15-03-2017|1|3|9|4

and 
b.csv

> date      |A|C|D|E
>   16-03-2017|2|9|3|4

And I would like to get the next output:

> date      |A|B|C|D|E
>   15-03-2017|1|3|9|4|0
>   16-03-2017|2|0|9|3|4

Any insights or suggestions are appreciated!

EDIT:
Thanks for all

These file examples are not always the same
sometimes it can have between 10 and 50 columns and between 1 and 30 rows (dates)

Comment: interesting task, could the initial files have multiple lines(more than two)?

Comment: This is not a task for `join`. Please remove the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem

I changed the way to get the data

Something like this:

```
today=$(date +%Y%m%d)
echo "DataBase "$(date +%d/%m/%Y)>/jdb"$today".txt
du -s $(ls -l|grep ^d|awk '{print $9})|awk '{print $2" "$1" "}'>>/jdb"$today".txt
```

the output is like:

jdb_20170507.txt:

```
database 07/05/2017
jdb_A 4345
jdb_CFX 7654
jdb_ZZXD 97865
```

jdb_20170508.txt:

```
database 08/05/2017
jdb_A 9876
jdb_CFX 7545
jdb_ZXCFG  2344
```

for this examples in jdb_20170508.txt was deleted the jdb_ZZXD database and created the jdb_ZXCFG database

with this structure I can use JOIN command:

```
x=0
touch jdbaux$x.txt
for jdbfile in $(ls -1t|grep jdb2)
  do
    y=$(($x+1))
    join -a1 -a2 -e0 -o auto --nocheck-order jdbaux$x.txt $jdbfile >jdbaux$y.txt
    rm jdbaux$x.txt
    x=$(($x+1))
done
```

This is my recursive JOIN rustic option for all the archives of the month

-a1= file one

-a2=file two

-e0=replace missing input fields with 0

-o auto= output automatic format

--nocheck-order =do not check that the input is correctly sorted

the output is like:
jdb_sizes201705.txt:

```
database 07/05/2017 08/05/2017
jdb_A 4345 9876
jdb_CFX 7654 7545
jdb_ZZXD 97865 0
jdb_ZXCFG 0 2344
```

and the last step is a pivote

```
cat jdb_sizes201705.txt |awk '
{ 
  for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)  {
    a[NR,i] = $i
  }
}
NF>p { p = NF }
END {    
    for(j=1; j<=p; j++) {
      str=a[1,j]
        for(i=2; i<=NR; i++){
          str=str" "a[i,j];
        }
        print str
    }
}'
```

Obtaining the expected output

```
database jdb_A jdb_CFX jdb_ZZXD jdb_ZXCFG
07/05/2017 4345 7654 97865 0
08/05/2017 9876 7545 0 2344
```

I know it's not the best solution but it works!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

something like this...

```
awk 'BEGIN  {FS=OFS="|"} 
     FNR==1 {split($0,h); next} 
            {c++; 
             for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
                {a[h[i],c]=$i; 
                 hall[h[i]]}} 
     END    {for(k in hall) printf "%s", k OFS; 
             print "";
             for(i=1;i<=c;i++) 
                {for(k in hall) printf "%s", ((k,i) in a?a[k,i]:0) OFS; 
                 print ""}}' file1 file2

A|B|C|D|E|date |
1|3|9|4|0|15-03-2017|
2|0|9|3|4|16-03-2017|
```

you can reorder the columns with some additional code, but perhaps a better solution will show up...

Comment: OMG, apologies for my inattentiveness (deleted answer). Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A slightly simpler solution using `sed`:

```
sed 's/$/|0/;1s/0/E/' a.csv; sed '1d;s/|/|0|/2' b.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

I am expanding my answer into a script for readability. You can use the script with the `awk -f` option. Starting with a `BEGIN` statement: specify `|` as your field separator, map an index to each header label using associative array and print the full header. For each file, map labels to indices on line 1. Then map labels to data on line 2 and replace empty data fields with "0". Print the filled out line and clear the arrays for the next file.

```
BEGIN{
    # field separator
    FS="|"

    # index:label mapping
    map[1]="date "; map[2]="A"; map[3]="B"
    map[4]="C"; map[5]="D"; map[6]="E"

    # print full header
    print "date |A|B|C|D|E"
}

# first line of each file, create index:label mapping
FNR==1{

    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        label[i]=$i
}

# next line of the file, create label:data mapping
FNR==2{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        data[label[i]]=$i

    # cycle through index:label mapping and print data
    # for each label or "0" if there is no data
    printf("%s", data["date "])
    for (i=2;i<=6;i++) {
        (data[map[i]]) ? s=data[map[i]] : s=0
        printf("|%s", s)
        }
    print ""  # print empty string for newline

    # delete arrays to start from scratch on the following file
    delete label  
    delete data
}
```

Result on the two example files:

```
$ awk -f joiner.awk a.csv b.csv 
date |A|B|C|D|E
15-03-2017|1|3|9|4|0
16-03-2017|2|0|9|3|4
```